# python time series resample to get correct count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have a 4 years monthly time series (index is timestamp).  Therefore ideally, I would have 4 jan rows, 4 feb rows, 4 mar rows, 4 apr rows .... and so on.

However, sometimes, I may get missed month or more.   Therefore, I may have 4 jan, 2 feb, 3 mar, 4 apr, 1 may ... and so on

I am trying to resample('MS').count() but this does not work as it count each month as one.   How do I groupby to get the correct count e.g; 4 jan, 2 feb, 3 mar, 4 apr, 1 may ... and so on.   and then average the values?

for example ... count of jan is 4 since I have 2 rows with Jan date.   However, count of Oct is 3 ... since I have 3 cot rows.   Average of apples sold in Jan is 13/4

I am trying to do this with resample, not by looping or pandas slicing, if possible.

```
df_= df_monthly.resample('MS').count()

Index       Apples_sold
1-1,2015  3
2-1,2015  5
3-1,2015  6
...
9-1,2015  7
10-1,2015  9
11-1,2015  6
12-1,2015  2
==================
1-1,2016  2
2-1,2016  5
3-1,2016  6
...
9-1,2016  7
10-1,2016  9
11-1,2016  6
12-1,2016  2
==================
1-1,2017  4
2-1,2017  5
3-1,2017  6
...
9-1,2017  7
10-1,2017  9
11-1,2017  6
12-1,2017  2
==================
1-1,2018  4
2-1,2018  5
3-1,2018  6
...
9-1,2018  7
```

Comment: Could you post a relevant self contained example and where it's going wrong to help debug

Comment: reposted.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) on the index values with a regex to pull the month.

Here's the DataFrame I used as an example:

```
             count
1 Feb 2018       1
8 Feb 2018       2
1 Mar 2018       3
8 Mar 2018       4
15 Mar 2018      5
1 Apr 2018       6
8 Apr 2018       7
15 Apr 2018      8
22 Apr 2018      9
```

And the code to extract:

```
month_re = r'(?P<month>[A-Za-z]+)'
months = df.groupby(df.index.str.extract(month_re, expand=False), axis=0)
for month, group in months:
    print(month, group.count())
```

Output:

```
Apr count    4
Feb count    2
Mar count    3
```

You could also use `sum()` to find out the number of apples sold each month, or whatnot.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing something like this:

> for month in df.index.month.unique():
>
> ```
>    df_month_avg = df[df.index.month == month].mean(axis=0, numeric_only=True)
> ```

For count, I just replaced mean() with count()

This seems to work ... even though my goal was to use a resample approach ... but I could not find a resample grouping key to do this.